# UI lag when play high frame rate multi-videos

Tags: c#, uwp, video-processing

For now, my app need to play two videos at once. My idea is using two MediaPlayerElements to play that two videos. My app run normally when it run in 
 a high perfomance PC, but when I run my App in lower performance tablet my App's UI is very lag. So hardware perfomance affected my App. In both cases, the usage of CPU and GPU are not very high (~25%).
I think my App run in a single core of CPU, so when the resouce of one core is exhausted, it can not make my videos smoothly. For now, I don't know how to make my app use full resource of CPU. 
If my prediction is true, please talk to me the right method to make my app use full resource of CPU.
Else, Can you have some suggestions for me. Thank you!
some information deal with my app:
1. video resolution: 480*640
2. frame rate: 99 frame per second
3. tested tablet: Intel Atom x5-Z8350 CPU @ 1.44GHz 1.44GHz; 4.00 GB RAM.
4. tested PC: Intel Core i3 7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz 3.90GHz; 16.00 GB RAM.

Comment: I have seen videos with 120 fps *(similar resolution when I remember correctly)* that laged on 'professional' players (MPC-HC) on a i5. CPU total usage was "only" about 70%, but the video had many lags, probably because the GPU usage was 100%. The problem you have can be in high frame rate. It is possible, that the speed of video transfer (to graphic card) is lacking. *(The video I had, was (almost definitely) incorrectly encoded. Try your video on any other player, how will this player react.

Comment: @Julo my videos are played normally when I play them singly (with another app that developed by me) or on professional players. the lag phenomena only appears when I play two videos at once.

Comment: Does the lag appear when you play to videos at once in something like VLC? In case it does, it really is not a UWP problem, but really the performance issue.

Comment: @MartinZikmund, I have just play two video at once, one in  Movie&TV and one in Window Media Player. The lag appears some times but the frequency is less than my my App (1:3 ratio). I put two MediaPlayerElements control in the same UI and play them parallelly by using MediaTimelineController. Have some wrong in my code, do you have some suggestion? thank you.